# How satoshi is programmed?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

> "Each Bitcoin is divisible into a hundred millionth of a Bitcoin
>   called satoshi These tiny fractions of a Bitcoin can be programmed to
>   represent assets other than money."

What here is meant by programming the tiny fractions (satoshi) ? Can anyone simplify that?

Comment: What is reference did you read?

Comment: https://youtu.be/LszOt51OjXU minute(18)in this video

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment

> youtu.be/LszOt51OjXU minute(18)in this video
>
> "Each Bitcoin is divisible into a hundred millionth of a Bitcoin called satoshi These tiny fractions of a Bitcoin can be programmed to represent assets other than money."

I think video citation is more generic, the Bitcoin is dividable in 8 parts and this a comune action with the money; an example.
*1 EUR = 100 cents*

The citation of Satoshi is programmed for more application id real life, this is not wrong but is this is a citation big generic.

An example, for use the microtransaction with bitcoin is used the protocol Lightning network, in the Lightning network protocol can be used the millsatoshi unit.

> can be programmed to represent assets other than money.

The citation is not wrong bu is generic because is possible used bitcoin for work with another blockchain called side-chain, an example liquid network

Some reference.

1. [Lightning Network](https://medium.com/@BlockchainEng/introduction-to-lightning-network-on-bitcoin-blockchain-68186623d491)
2. The introduction of how [bitcoin work](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook)
3. [Liquid network](https://en.cryptonomist.ch/2019/06/08/what-is-the-liquid-network-sidechain/)

Comment: To thank you use the votes on stackoverflow, if you think my answer is helpful, express your vote.